# Why does Ant Designs Tree component render so slow when expanding?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, antd, react-component

I'm building an React component/EntityBrowser that holds a Tree component from ant.design. It's a prototype going into production soon. It's still based on create-react-app. State is managed through Redux.

I've tried searching for answers using both google and Stackoverflow. The consensus seems to be; whenever the Tree components treeData prop receives too much data, it slows down the rendering process, because each of the TreeNodes needs to be re-rendered every time the Tree is expanded. Since more data means slower rendering for each of the TreeNodes - well.. adding more TreeNodes also means slower rendering by the factor the extra data adds.

I don't know if this is the real reason for the overall performance. I've profiled the component and indeed adding more data results in worse rendering times and same goes for the amount of nodes. I would expect this. I'm just surprised by the rate the Tree performance, both when adding new nodes dynamically, but also when expanding it, deteriorates. It does not require many nodes. After only a few nodes with minimal data, it's already too slow to be usable.

This is the Tree component:

```
                <Tree
                    rootClassName={dark ? "dark-tree" : ""}
                    style={{ borderRadius: "0" }}
                    blockNode={true}
                    onExpand={onExpand}
                    onSelect={onSelect}
                    selectedKeys={selectedKeys}
                    expandedKeys={expandedKeys}
                    treeData={treeData}
                    titleRender={TreeNode}
                />
```

These are the props handling onExpand and onSelect.

```
    const onExpand = (expandedKeys) => {
        dispatch(entityBrowserActions.updateExpandedKeys(expandedKeys));
    };

    const onSelect = (selectedKeys, { event }) => {
        if (handleSelection) handleSelection(selectedKeys);
        dispatch(entityBrowserActions.updateSelectedKeys(selectedKeys));
    };
```

The handleSelection call tells the app to show the right "scenario" based on the current entityStructure. We are choosing between them in the EntityBrowser/Tree itself.

The treeData is generated with:

```
    const createTreeData = (entityStructure) => {
        return entityStructure.map((item) => {
            const itemSelectable = !selectedKeys.includes(item.key);
            let title = (<span>{item.name}</span>);
            let itemObj = {};
            let newName = (e) => onNameChange(e, item.key);
            let stopEdit = () => handleStopEdit(item.key);

            if (editable && editingEntities[item.key] == true) {
                title = (
                    <Input
                        value={item.name}
                        onChange={ newName }
                        onBlur={ stopEdit }
                    />
                );
            }

            if (item.children) {
                itemObj = {
                    title,
                    key: item.key,
                    selectable: itemSelectable, // Selectable only if not already selected 
                    checkable: false,
                    children: createTreeData(item.children),
                };
            } else {
                itemObj = {
                    title,
                    key: item.key,
                    selectable: itemSelectable, 
                }
            }
            return itemObj;
        });
    };
```

The "design" of the treenodes is added with the titleRender prop:

```
   const TreeNode = (value, record) => {
        const handleEdit = () => handleStartEdit(value.key);
        const handleClose = () => handleClosePopup(value.key, deletePopoverVisible[value.key]);
        const handleDeleteAndClose = () => {
            handleDelete(value.key);
            handleClosePopup(value.key, false);
        }

        return (
            <div className="tree-title">
                {value.title}
                {editable ? (
                    <div style={{}}>
                        <Button
                            type="text"
                            style={{ padding: "2px 4px" }}
                            onClick={ handleEdit }>
                            <EditOutlined style={{ fontSize: "1.1rem" }} />
                        </Button>
                        <Popover
                            visible={ deletePopoverVisible[value.key] }
                            onVisibleChange={ handleClose }
                            content={
                                <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
                                    <Button
                                        type="text"
                                        style={{ color: "red" }}
                                        onClick={ handleDeleteAndClose }>
                                        Delete
                                    </Button>
                                    <Button
                                        type="text"
                                        onClick={ handleClose }>
                                        Cancel
                                    </Button>
                                </div>
                            }
                            trigger="click">
                            <Button type="text" style={{ padding: "2px 4px" }}>
                                <DeleteOutlined style={{ fontSize: "1.1rem" }} />
                            </Button>
                        </Popover>
                    </div>
                ) : null}
            </div>
        );
    };
```

I've tried to remove all the "unnecessary" props like onSelect, titleRender, blockNode, etc. When doing this it does give a speed up but even if I remove everything but the bare minimum it is still painfully slow. Initially all the function calls happened on props inline and now I've "pulled them out" to try and gain some speed. Got a little bit - but not nearly enough.

I don't know how to proceed here. I'm hoping someone can point me to something super obvious that I'm missing.

Everything and nothing worked.